# Change language in shopify by importing csv file

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

When I'm trying to use Multilanguage in shoplifty by importing the csv file it show the issue "the file is not uploading" and "Skip the type"?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LqTe.png)

When I remove the type then it show this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElzKn.png)